# Toggle child table from Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table structure like below.When I click first row It Toggles.Now I want to click the checkbox to expand all rows.I am trying to do Grouped collapsable table.

```
<div id=divdg">
<input type="checkbox" id="chkdg"/>Expand/Collapse all
<table id="Table1" cellpadding="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
    <tr class="headerd headerstyle">
        <td>dg1</td>
        <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td>data3</td>
        <td>data4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div style="position: relative; left: 25px; overflow: auto; display:inline-table;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
                <tr class="headerd headerstyle">
                    <td>dg2</td>
                    <td>Row</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="child">
                    <td>data1</td>
                    <td>data2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="child">
                    <td>data3</td>
                    <td>data4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
</div>
</div>

 $("tr.headerd").click(function () {
            $("tr.child", $(this).parent()).slideToggle("fast");
        });

    $("#chkdg").click(function () {
        //$(".headerd",$(this).children()).slideToggle("fast");
        $("#divdg").children() .slideToggle("fast");
    });
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/ZL5Vb/1](http://jsfiddle.net/ZL5Vb/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this piece of code:

```
$("tr.headerd").click(function () {
        $("tr.child", $(this).parent()).slideToggle("fast");
    });

    $("#chkdog").change(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {$(".child").slideUp("fast");}
        else
        {$(".child").slideDown("fast");}

    });
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5gkK/)

Answer (score 1):

This will fire the "click" event on every "tr.headerd":

```
$("#chkdog").click(function () {       
    $("tr.headerd").each(function(){$(this).click();});
});
```

Comment: The problem with that is that will alter the state of each table. So if one table is collapsed, the other one is opened, and you run this script it will just invert the state, it will not collapse or expand all the tables as the checkbox label suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$("#divdg").children() .slideToggle("fast");
```

Try:

```
$("#Table1").find('tr.child') .slideToggle("fast");
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like this:

```
<tr id="row1" class="headerd headerstyle">
    <td>dg1</td>
    <td>Row</td>
</tr>
<tr class="child">
    <td id="row2">data1</td>
    <td>data2</td>
</tr>
<tr id="row3" class="child">
    <td>data3</td>
    <td>data4</td>
</tr>

$("#chkdg").click(function () {
    $("#row1").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#chkdog").click(function () {
            //$(".headerd",$(this).children()).slideToggle("fast");
            if($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
            $("tr.child", $(this).parent()).slideDown("fast");
            }
            else {
            $("tr.child", $(this).parent()).slideUp("fast");
            }
        });
```